# export hashsmap to xlsx using nested for each loop

Tags: hashmap

I have below loop trying to printout keys and values stored in a hashmap

```
 // Create the first row corresponding to the header
            Row header = Sheet.createRow(0);
            int headerIndex = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : resultsToPrint.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                header.createCell(headerIndex).setCellValue(key);
                int rowIndex = 1;
                
                for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                    // Creating row 
                    Row row = Sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
                    // create cell
                    row.createCell(headerIndex).setCellValue(value);

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                headerIndex++;

            }
```

the results I am getting looks like this:
[This is what gets printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXAUu.png)

what I need this loop to do, is to populate the values of the second column as well and if I add a third column, it needs to populate the values for the third column etc.

Please assist